# read properties from multiple property files iteratively and do some action using a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have 2 directories one has a single `inputs.properties` file and one of the property in this file is `script_properties_path`. My task is to get the path from this property and list all the files  which are again different set of property files. Now I have to read all properties from each file in the path and perform some action. I am able to read the properties but when I set them to some variables I get empty string.
inputs.properties:

```
WORKSPACE_DIR=C:\Workspace_LSV\
PACKAGES_PATH=QA_AUTO_SELENIUM\Selenium\Automation2.0\
RESULTS_DIR=C:\Results\
PROPERTIES_DIR=D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp
```

file in D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp:

```
LSV1.properties
LSV2.properties
```

LSV-437_LSV-436.properties:

```
FILENAME=/cs/gui/tests/admin/auditing/AuditTestVersionAndFuncMenuItems.java
CLASSNAME=cs.gui.tests.admin.auditing.AuditTestVersionAndFuncMenuItems
```

LS_435.properties:

```
FILENAME=/cs/gui/tests/admin/auditing/TestAuditingShortcut.java
CLASSNAME=cs.gui.tests.admin.auditing.TestAuditingShortcut
```

My Code:

```
@echo "batch program"
@echo off
For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%A IN (inputs.properties) DO (SET %%A=%%B)
    IF "%%A"=="WORKSPACE_DIR" SET WORKSPACE_DIR=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="PACKAGES_PATH" SET PACKAGES_PATH=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="PROPERTIES_DIR" SET PROPERTIES_DIR=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="RESULTS_DIR" SET RESULTS_DIR=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="BROWSER" SET BROWSER=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="APP_URL" SET APP_URL=%%B
    IF "%%A"=="CLASSPATH" SET CLASSPATH=%%B
    
@echo "WORKSPACE_DIR %WORKSPACE_DIR%"
@echo "PACKAGES_PATH %PACKAGES_PATH%"
@echo "PROPERTIES_DIR %PROPERTIES_DIR%"
@echo "RESULTS_DIR %RESULTS_DIR%"
@echo "BROWSER %BROWSER%"
@echo "APP_URL %APP_URL%"

FOR %%D in (%PROPERTIES_DIR%\*.*) DO (
    @echo "FILE:%%D "
    
    For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E IN (%%D) DO (set %%E=%%F)
        IF "%%E"=="FILENAME" SET FILENAME=%%F
        IF "%%E"=="CLASSNAME" SET CLASSNAME=%%F
    @echo %FILENAME%
    @echo %CLASSNAME%   

) 
cmd /k
```

Output:

```
"batch program"
"WORKSPACE_DIR C:\Workspace_LSV\"
"PACKAGES_PATH products\comp\qa.auto.selenium\22.4.0-branch\pkg\QA_AUTO_SELENIUM\OT_Selenium\Automation2.0\"
"PROPERTIES_DIR D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp"
"FILE:D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp\LSV-437_LSV-436.properties "
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
"FILE:D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp\LS_435.properties "
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

When I run the following code:

```
FOR %%D in (%PROPERTIES_DIR%\*.*) DO (
    @echo "FILE:%%D "
    
    For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E IN (%%D) DO (
        IF "%%E"=="FILENAME" SET FILENAME=%%F
        IF "%%E"=="CLASSNAME" SET CLASSNAME=%%F
        @echo %%E
        @echo %%F
        @echo %FILENAME%    
        @echo %CLASSNAME%
    )
)
```

output is:

```
"batch program"
"WORKSPACE_DIR C:\Workspace_LSV\"
"PACKAGES_PATH products\comp\qa.auto.selenium\22.4.0-branch\pkg\QA_AUTO_SELENIUM\OT_Selenium\Automation2.0\"
"PROPERTIES_DIR D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp"
"RESULTS_DIR C:\Results\"
"BROWSER chrome"
"APP_URL https://otcs2.xsogpreprod.opentext.cloud/cs/cs"
"FILE:D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp\LSV-437_LSV-436.properties "
FILENAME
/CSTests16_2/src/com/opentext/auto/cs/gui/tests/admin/auditing/AuditTestVersionAndFuncMenuItems.java
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
CLASSNAME
com.opentext.auto.cs.gui.tests.admin.auditing.AuditTestVersionAndFuncMenuItems
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
"FILE:D:\Work\Projects\xECM\BatchRunner\temp\LS_435.properties "
FILENAME
/CSTests16_2/src/com/opentext/auto/cs/gui/tests/admin/auditing/TestAuditingShortcut.java
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
CLASSNAME
com.opentext.auto.cs.gui.tests.admin.auditing.TestAuditingShortcut
ECHO is off.
ECHO is off.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
FOR %%D in (%PROPERTIES_DIR%\*.*) DO (
    @echo "FILE:%%D "
    
    For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E IN (%%D) DO (set %%E=%%F)
        rem Redundant IF "%%E"=="FILENAME" SET FILENAME=%%F
        rem Redundant IF "%%E"=="CLASSNAME" SET CLASSNAME=%%F
) 

@echo %FILENAME%
@echo %CLASSNAME%

cmd /k
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Nick Abbot. But here I have to access the variables CLASSNAME & FILENAME inside the first for loop. And I have to perform some action for all the files.
Just as an Example:

`FOR %%D in (%PROPERTIES_DIR%\*.*) DO (
    echo "FILE:%%D "
 
 For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%E IN (%%D) DO (set %%E=%%F)
     rem Redundant IF "%%E"=="FILENAME" SET FILENAME=%%F
  rem Redundant IF "%%E"=="CLASSNAME" SET CLASSNAME=%%F
 
 echo %FILENAME% 
        echo %CLASSNAME%

 cd %CLASSNAME%
 java -classpath %CLASSPATH% %FILENAME%
  
)`

Comment: I don't think you can, they won't exist yet.